# Determine the current output to the speaker C++ Beginner

Tags: c++, volume, speaker

Recently, I've began learning C++ in college and was asked to make a looping sequence of "*" with the sequence going like this:

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
*********
*******
*****
***
*
```

[continues indefinitely until it goes x lines, where x is specified at the start]

How I did it if you need a visualisation:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int hFar=0; //Variable that will be used to find out how many parts into the sequence the user would like to travel.
unsigned long int fibSequenceA = 0; //Unsigned doesn't overflow as easilly. This is the first value of the fibunacci sequence, it's defined as 0 to start.
unsigned long int fibSequenceB = 1; // Second Value of fibbunacci sequence. Defined at 1 to start.
int sPart = 1;//Used for the * sequence, it is the part of the sequence that the loop is on. It changes dynamically by either +2 or -2 every loop.
int cValue = 0;// also for the * sequence, it is the current number of * typed.
int sDirection = 0; // used to change from subtracting 2, and adding 2.
int redo = 1; // used to ensure that every 9 and every 1 the sequence repeats that number a second time. Starts at one because the sequence starts with only 1 single * rather then 2 *.

cout << "How far into the second sequence would you like to travel?" << endl; //Requests how far into the * sequence you'd like to go.
        cin >> hFar; //inputs answer into variable.
        for(int i = 0; i < hFar; i++ ) {//begins for statement. Notice there's no hfar/2. There will only be 1 output per line now.
            while(cValue < sPart) { //Basic while loop to input the ammount of * on the current line. Works by adding a * depending on what part of the sequence it is.
                cout << "*"; //self explainitory.
                cValue++; //raises the cValue in order to keep track of the current number of *. Also prevents infinite loop.
            }
            if(sPart == 9 && redo == 0) { //Checks if the sequence part is 9, meaning that the value begins to reduce to 1 again. But first, it must repeat 9 to keep with the sequence.
                sDirection = 3; //sets the direction to 3 to make sure that the value of sPart stays at 9, instead of reducing by 2.
                redo = 1; //resets the redo.
                cValue = 8; //changes the value of the current number of 8. Not sure if this is important, It gets done again later to make sure anyway.
                sPart = 9; //Changes the sPart to 9, the needed number of *. Also redone later, but to make sure, I kept this here.
            }
            else if(sPart == 9 && redo == 1) { // if the sequence has already redone the 9th *
                sDirection = 1; //sets the direction to 1; The sequence will reverse.
                redo = 0; //returns redo to 0 to ensure that next time it reaches 1, it repeats the 1 * again.
            }
            else if(sPart == 1 && redo == 0) {  //when the value reaches one for the second time, it needs to repeat that value.
                sDirection = 3; //sets the direction to 3 again to stop the change.
                redo = 1; //resets the redo.
                cValue  = 0;//also might be redundant.
            }
            else if(sPart == 1 && redo == 1) { // stops the duplicate number of *
                sDirection = 0; //sets the direction to +2 again.
                redo = 0;//resets the redo.
            }
                            Sleep(50);
            cout << endl; //adds a new line. This ensures that we get a new line after every part rather then 900 * on one line.
            if(sDirection == 0) { //if the direction is positive.
                sPart += 2; //adds 2 to the spart to keep with the sequence.
                cValue = 0; //resets the cValue to 0 so the while statement works again.
            }
            else if(sDirection == 1) { //if the direction is negative
                sPart -=2; //subtracts 2 from the spart to keep with the sequence.
                cValue = 0; //resets the cValue to keep the while statement working.
            }
            else if(sDirection = 3) { //if the change is 
            //Could have been done differently. Could have just set the values to themselves, but it wasn't working. not sure why.
                if(sPart == 9){ //if the spart is currently 9.
                    sPart = 9; //keeps it at 9.
                    cValue = 0; //resets the cValue.
                        }
                else if(sPart == 1){ //if the spart is currently 1
                    sPart = 1; //keeps it at one. 
                    cValue = 0; //resets the cValue.
                }
            }
        }
    return 1;//ends the code.
}
```

[Sorry about all the comments, I'm trying to make sure I understand what I'm doing, like I said, I'm learning :)]

While fooling around with the loops, I ended up putting the Sleep() function in, so that it produced a wave effect when generating the sequence. This got me thinking, and I wanted to know if it would be possible to make the command prompt act like a makeshift volume visualizer. (The more "*" the higher the volume at that point in time).

So, when playing a song on my computer, the program would find the total output to the speaker, and put a number of "*" that correlate to that volume, and would continue this until the program ends, producing (hopefully) an interesting effect. (if you're confused, play a song on your computer, right click on the speaker icon on the task bar, and click open volume mixer, and look at the volume levels change, this is the type of effect that I'm looking for)

Would this be possible? I've been googling the issue, (found things like [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374921(v=vs.85).aspx) and I've found a number of ways to find out the current MASTER volume, and change that, But I'm looking for more of the actual volume that one hears, not the maximum volume that my speakers can output.

Here's somewhat of what I'm looking to do.

```
int sPart = x; //x = the current output of the speaker
int cValue = 0 //the current number of "*" output
while([somecondition I'm not sure when i want the sequence to stop yet]) {
while(cValue < sPart) { 
                cout << "*";
                cValue++; 
            }
        cout << endl; //ends the current line, making room for the next value of the volume.
        Sleep(50); //waits 50ms before finding the next volume value.
        sPart = [current speaker value]; //finds the value of the speaker again.
        cValue = 0; //resetting the number of "*" back to zero.
        }
//I just reused the variables from my original code.
```

Would this be possible? If so, would a beginner be capable of this? Again, If so, how would it be done?

Comment: please do not feel offended, but honestly this is the best example i have seen so far for too much comments making a code almost unreadable

Comment: You have a typo in the line `else if(sDirection = 3)`, you should be using the `==` operator.

Comment: are you aware that it is not trivial to know the volume of sound at a given point in time? Sound is a wave and its amplitude is the volume. At one point in time the wave isnt moving...

Comment: I know it's alot of comments, My instructor wants me to type comments on every line to help me "Learn" I just copied the code I already have, also, I ususally use a really bright color for the comments so that it's easier to ignore them, They are kinda distracting. tobi303, I'm trying to get the "volume" of the speakers as heard by a person, so for for example, if one has their computer at full volume, but isn't playing any music, the computer will not make a sound, and the code should get "0", or if the computer is making a sound, it would be > 0.

Comment: Open Kastle, Thank you. I didn't notice that.

Comment: cout << "*"; //self explainitory. *This is self explanatory but this isn't? lol* sPart = 9; //keeps it at 9.